# Spring 5 cache not work for @Cachable (CacheInterceptor is not in call stack)?

Tags: java, spring, caching, aop

I enable caching for a public method by adding @Cachable annotation as follow:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "saas_setting", //
        key = "#key")
public Setting get(String key) { ... }
```

In the other hand I add cacheManager bean:

```
<bean id="cacheManager"
    class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                name="saas_setting" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I enable AOP:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy 
    proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Then enable cache:

```
<cache:annotation-driven 
    mode="aspectj"
    proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

How ever, the result is not cached and the method is called when ever is called from other part of the system.

I put a brake point in the method and check call stack: There is no CachInterceptor in the stack?!

---

EDIT:

This is the complete configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.3.xsd">

    <!-- Enable AspectJ style of Spring AOP -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy 
        proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <!-- Enable cache -->
    <cache:annotation-driven 
        mode="aspectj"
        proxy-target-class="true"/>


    <bean id="cacheManager"
        class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
            <set>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                    name="saas_setting" />
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="applicationProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>resources/server.properties</value>
                <value>resources/modules/*.properties</value>
                <value>resources/jetty/*.properties</value>
                <value>resources/db/#{systemProperties['db.dialect']}.properties
                </value>
                <value>resources/db/#{systemProperties['db.orm']}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <import resource="../context/beans-*.xml" />
</beans>
```

---

EDIT:

Baed on Spring documentation:

> The default advice mode for processing caching annotations is "proxy" which allows for interception of calls through the proxy only; local calls within the same class cannot get intercepted that way. For a more advanced mode of interception, consider switching to "aspectj" mode in combination with compile-time or load-time weaving.

In some part of my codes, private methods are going to be cached. So I have to use AspectJ with load-time weaving.

Comment: Please add your complete xml configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the aspectJ mode of caching you need spring-aspects.jar in your classpath. its unclear why do you want to go with aspectj proxy instead of default one.

since you are using aspectj mode for proxy, you need to setup the loadtime weaving as well.

The load time weaving can be enabled using:

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

Also the method on which you are using must be from concrete class as you are using `proxy-target-class="true"`

Comment: Dear Sangam, How could I check if cache work or troubleshooting? Is it possible to debug and trace spring code and find the reason?